# Can we use a tag to identify 'core hacks'?

Tags: discussion

Stemming from [this discussion](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/907/what-do-we-do-with-hack-core-answers), would it be good for us to tag questions that involve core hacks? I am thinking something that is non-offensive involving the word 'trac', since trac is the proper place to air out these requests. Currently, we have no tags officially classifying a trac-related question.

We could use something like:

- trac-feature-request
- trac-bug

Any suggestions?

Comment: +1 on adding these tags

Comment: I am especially fond of `trac-bug`, though I've not actually run into too many such questions. Also, I think anything that would fit `trac-bug` would qualify as *out of scope*, and the question would get closed, anyway.

Comment: One thing to keep in mind when deciding on the name of the tag is whether it'll be obvious and easy to discover. If a new user comes in and posts a question that exposes a problem in Wordpress core, will they know that [trac-bug] is the tag they want?

Comment: @AnnaLear I think the [trac-bug] tag would be more for moderators or experienced users to add to a questions once it's identified as a trac issue.

Comment: I agree, what about `core-trac`? A user would likely type the word `core` in if anything. Not sure if that tag would make sense though.

Comment: @Jared - Yes, agree. +1

Comment: @ChipBennett - What say you about `core-trac`?

Comment: I think i still prefer `trac-bug` and `trac-feature-request`. I doubt that "core" would have any more meaning to an end user than "trac" does. Besides, I figure these tags would be added retrospectively by the *community*, rather than by the person asking the question - so we should make them as meaningful/useful to the *community* as possible.

Comment: @ChipBennett Since I'm a bit of a n00b at this part, is there a proper procedure to adding new tags like this?

Comment: @BrianFegter um, I'm with you. :) I suppose it's just a matter of establishing a convention, and then using it. I've actually already used `trac-bug` once, so it should exist. Somebody just needs to write up the tag wiki.